# Windows Programming Languages (GUI) that doesn't require installing any framework/dependency

Tags: windows, programming-languages

I use C#/VB.NET most of the time to write windows applications.

But this happens when my customers need an app that doesn't require a framework (e.g **.Net 4**) to be installed on destination system . So the exe file can run without installing any dependency.

I know about **C/C++** but writing GUI applications in them is so hard.
I heard about **D** language, but it seems to be very fresh and there is no (not enough) documentation at all.

Also there is **Delphi** but it's so expensive.

Is there anything else out there ?

note: I prefer compiled languages over interpreted ones.

Comment: @JosephH oh please.... I still remember those VB6 days back then. so much pain lol

Comment: Could you not package .NET with the installer for your application?

Comment: @Whymarrh Actually I am doing it for every .NET project. but this application is asked to be delivered by web and the customers have very slow net (around 128Kbit/s ADSL).

Comment: My first thought would be a JavaScript application (assuming that they're using a decent browser). That way you could have a project that requires no dependencies* and can be run client-side (little server communication). But you should update the question with all the requirements that need to be met (to allow for a proper answer).

Comment: Since XP SP 2 .NET Framework 3.5 is already part of Windows. So you should have a good time with .NET except for servers where this feature is not installed.

Comment: +1 for Alois's comment. You don't *have* to code against .NET4. You can code against earlier versions of the framework and trust that they'll already be on the target machine. Note that pretty much almost everything else either has DLL dependencies or compiles those dependencies into the final EXE, making for a bloated distributable. (Even pure C has a runtime. the code that implements stdlib and stdio has to live *somewhere*...) Me, I would go with .NET2.

Comment: It can be rather galling targetting .net 2 and having to miss out lots of the features that make C# so great to code in.

Comment: what's the meaning of his 'expensive' means...? is it training costly, or time consuming learning curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cost is a factor, since you reject Delphi, how about FreePascal with the Lazarus IDE. It's just hit version 1.0 and is of a very high standard.

Comment: I just installed both of them, the IDE seems to be very similar to delphi. But if I want to look up for something, Can I use Delphi documentations ? Do they work the same way? the controls, the coding, debugging errors and building the project.

Comment: Well, Lazarus IDE is similar to Delphi 7. But if you want documentation, I'd use the Lazarus and FPC documentation.

Comment: waaah... they're still alive! :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Understand the point of the libraries (DLLs): to avoid you having to bundle the common functions/methods/classes into your application *every time*. With that in mind, I would ask *why the requirement to not install libraries on the destination?*

Is it disk space? Required effort? Fear/Paranoia? (Lack of) expertise?

I would look to address the *root cause* of this "requirement" rather than try to work around it.

There are ways to statically link whatever functions/methods/classes/etc. your code needs directly into your binary.

If you go away from .NET and wander into the [wonderful world of Windows assembly programming](https://www.grc.com/smgassembly.htm) (warning: near-vertical learning curve), you can write tiny, tiny apps (we're talking a few K) that require nothing external.

Comment: It's about Delivering the product application to the user. It should be done by web and as I explained to @Whymarrh, they have very slow net. on the other side, installing the framework is time consuming and sometimes I get report users run into errors while doing that.

Comment: I hear you. Sounds like the perfect excuse to burn all the libs onto a CD and drop-ship it to 'em. For US$20-30 (i.e., a pittance), your problem would be solved.

Comment: ok let me tell you what kind of application I am asked to write. It's a small app that stays in background and notify the user if the specific website got a rss update. and this program is gonna be put on the web for people to download. So you want me to tell them to spend $20 for each visitor and ship a cd to them worldwide ? when the application won't even reach 1Mg of size (without the framework installer)

Comment: I understand the desire to be dependency free. Ship a single exe which can run from anywhere. xcopy install. No need to write install packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a GUI compiler for Windows that uses no framework, then you want Visual Basic Version 6, which hasn't been updated since 1998.

If you want a web scripting language for Windows that uses no framework, then you want Classic ASP, which sadly hasn't been updated since 2000.

Classic ASP rocked.  It was miles better than the .NET framework.  Microsoft is run by idiots.  Perl and PHP are just stepchildren of Classic ASP.  Classic ASP was the last good development tool that Microsoft ever made.  What kind of idiots would assume that an overbearing framework would be suitable for all software development?  The .NET framework is an ugly, bloated circus of auto-generated code that pours ice down the pants of real developers.